# Is the Gravatar icon for Stack users repeatable or unique?

Tags: discussion, users, gravatar

I just seems that each Stack user has a default auto generated icon when they create an account.

Is this Image/Icon unique or repeatable?

What is the tool/software to generate this image for millions of new users?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeatable"?

Comment: Also - I guess you need to lookup gravatar. And how they are generated. Stack Overflow does not generate them.

Comment: More then one user have same Icon - "repeatable"

Comment: Those are hash-based, thus collisions are possible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon

Comment: It's based on an MD5 hash of the user's email address.  MD5 hash collisions are not only possible, but they are relatively easy to create on purpose https://www.bing.com/search?q=md5+collisions&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN

Comment: Currently SO has about 5.5 million accounts (per the [/users](http://stackoverflow.com/users) page). How many unique elements are there, per user icon? How many colors? Guesstimate, then divide the number of accounts by it. You will end up with a pretty large number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for two or more Stack Exchange users to have the same icon. For example, I know there is one user who uses the same image as Tim Post. Both use the same picture of a monkey wearing a hat.

The default image comes from Gravatar, and is generated from your e-mail address. It is possible for two different e-mail addresses to result in the same icon, but this is unlikely.

Comment: `and is generated from your e-mail address`, it's generated from email address?? How?

Comment: They are based on an MD5 hash of your address. There is some more info in [this answer on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148440/168333); apparently [this](http://www.puls200.de/?p=316) is an implementation of the algorithm (download at the bottom of the link; haven't tried it myself).